# unable to decrease element size in flexbox container and allign items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a front end project where I have a `flexbox  container` in the `bottom` of my website  that I want to store `contact list elements` in . The problem is that I want to add a `square` logo of my website as a `flexbox` element which I am unable to do correctly
The correct `display` I would like is seen in the picture below with the `red` logo with the required size and text next to it .
[image]
With my code however I cannot change the size of the red square logo as in the pic above and allign my items correctly and I cannot seem to find what is wrong .

```css
.contact-section{
    position: relative;
}

.contact-container{
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}

.contact-container div{
   padding:50px;
   margin:10px; 
}

.contact-container h1 ,h5{
    color:white;
}

address span{
    color:white;
}

#addr::before{
    content: " ";
}

#tel::before{
    content: "";
}

#mail{
    position: absolute;
    top:31%;
}

.bottom-square{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 2%;
}

.in-bot span{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class = "contact-section">
      <div class = "contact-container">
        <div> 
          <h5>DS <br/> AIRLINES</h5>
          <div class = "bottom-square">
            <div class="in-bot">
              <span id = "DS2">DS</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Find us at </h1>
          <address>
            <span id = "addr"><strong>Address</strong> :Karaoli kai Dimitriou 80 , Pireaus</span> <br/>
            <span id = "tel"><strong>Phone number</strong>  : 690000000</span> <br/>
            <span id = "mail">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              <strong>Email</strong> : bill@gmail.com
            </span> <br/><br/>

            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3146.505748604938!2d23.651267315179386!3d37.94197547972935!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x14a1bbefab3cde1b%3A0xcfae6e711f7b9d2a!2zzprOsc-BzrHOv867zq4gzrrOsc65IM6UzrfOvM63z4TPgc6vzr_PhSA4MCwgzqDOtc65z4HOsc65zqzPgiAxODUgMzQ!5e0!3m2!1sel!2sgr!4v1595690997204!5m2!1sel!2sgr" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>

          </address> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to allign my two items as in the pic above and reduce my square size. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you need such a result? if something needs to be redone, I'll redo it.

```css
.contact-section{
    position: relative;
}

.contact-container{
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}

.contact-containe-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.contact-container div{
   /*padding:50px;*/
   margin:10px; 
}

.contact-container h1 ,h5{
    color:white;
}

address span{
    color:white;
}

#addr::before{
    content: " ";
}

#tel::before{
    content: "";
}

#mail{
    position: absolute;
    top:31%;
}

.bottom-square{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    background-color: red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 2%;
}

.in-bot span{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class = "contact-section">
      <div class = "contact-container">
        <div class="contact-containe-box"> 
          <h5>DS <br/> AIRLINES</h5>
          <div class = "bottom-square">
            <div class="in-bot">
              <span id = "DS2">DS</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Find us at </h1>
          <address>
            <span id = "addr"><strong>Address</strong> :Karaoli kai Dimitriou 80 , Pireaus</span> <br/>
            <span id = "tel"><strong>Phone number</strong>  : 690000000</span> <br/>
            <span id = "mail">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              <strong>Email</strong> : bill@gmail.com
            </span> <br/><br/>

            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3146.505748604938!2d23.651267315179386!3d37.94197547972935!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x14a1bbefab3cde1b%3A0xcfae6e711f7b9d2a!2zzprOsc-BzrHOv867zq4gzrrOsc65IM6UzrfOvM63z4TPgc6vzr_PhSA4MCwgzqDOtc65z4HOsc65zqzPgiAxODUgMzQ!5e0!3m2!1sel!2sgr!4v1595690997204!5m2!1sel!2sgr" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>

          </address> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```